# Bing Translation APIs with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, multilingual

I keep seeing articles stating that you can use Bing Translation APIs for Multilingual SharePoint Online. Has anyone tried this? If so, how do you set it up?

Comment: it might help to share links to the articles you're referring to.

Comment: This is a link to an article that states that Machine Translation Services are deprecated and recommends using Bing translation APIs: https://www.sharepointeurope.com/understanding-the-deprecation-of-sharepoint-variations/ . When you follow the Bing translation API link and then the SharePoint link from there, you end up on a page which refers to setting up Variations which, if I understand correctly, are deprecated in SharePoint on-line. It is frustrating when you here about a way to do something but cannot find any documentation on how to set it up. It is almost like it goes in circles.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the article that Kerri linked to. It is very difficult to do this with classic pages, and nearly with modern pages. There is a bit more detail about it in my blog [here](http://blog.icefire.ca/post/machine-translation-service-variations-are-on-the-way-out)